# Is equal curved surface areas a coincidence

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, surfaces, solid-geometry

If we take a cylinder of height $2x$ and radius $x$, as well as a sphere of radius $x$, we notice that they have the same curved surface area.

Also, if we take the frustum of a cone such that it has base radii $R$ and $r$ ($R>r$) and slant height $l$, and we take a complete cone with base radius $R+r$ and slant height $l$, we notice that they have the same curved surface area.

**Is there any simple logical reason why this happens?**

Of course, one logical proof would be to simply derive the respective formulae and substitute the values. That would still imply that these are just coincidences. Is there any simpler method, preferably a somewhat visual one from which it becomes obvious why these instances occur?

Comment: The tomb of Archimedes carried a sculpture illustrating his favorite mathematical proof, consisting of a sphere and a cylinder of the same height and diameter. Archimedes had proven that the volume and surface area of the sphere are two thirds that of the cylinder including its bases. In 75 BC, 137 years after his death, the Roman orator Cicero was serving as quaestor in Sicily. He had heard stories about the tomb of Archimedes, but none of the locals was able to give him the location. Eventually he found the tomb near the Agrigentine gate in Syracuse, in a neglected condition and overgrown...

Comment: Oh, well. The projection of the surface of the sphere, sideways onto the rounded surface of the cylinder, is area preserving. This can be done in ordinary calculus, but makes more sense if you've had multivariable. It is not just the total surface area.

Comment: @Will Jagy - love history asides!

Comment: @WillJagy I don't know calculus.